# How should I understand "Save for Development Deployment" in Xcode for iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, ad-hoc-distribution, app-distribution

In Xcode 7.0 or above,when we archive the project and want to export the archive file as .ipa file,we have the four options:

[image]

We have a new option:`"Save for Development Deployment"`.

I don't know what's the difference between `"Save for Ad Hoc Deployment"` and `"Save for Development Deployment"`.

I called the Apple official support phone service for help,but he told me he's not clear and if I want to get more technical details,I can send emails to the professional help,and then he only sent me some official documentation on the Apple.com.

I have searched the Apple official documentation,I found this:

[App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

### Exporting Your App for Testing Outside the Store

> To distribute your app to users with designated devices, select “Save
>   for Ad Hoc Deployment.” The app will be code signed with the
>   distribution certificate.
>
> To distribute your app for internal testing, select “Save for
>   Development Deployment.” The app will be code signed with your
>   development certificate.

Acorrding to the above words.It seems that:

**Same point:**
*Both of them are for internal use.*

**Different points:**
*1.“Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.” for internal distribution,but “Save for Development Deployment.” for internal testing?

2.The difference between “Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.” and “Save for Development Deployment.” is distribution certificate and development certificate?*

Note:I have heard that "development certificate" belongs to the individual person but distribution certificate belongs to the whole team,I'm not quite sure about this.

***So,who can tell me what's the purpose of  "Save for Development Deployment",and what's the difference between "Save for Development Deployment" and “Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.”?***

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) As apple integrated testflight in itunes connect so when you select "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" then you can distribute your app to users with designated devices. The app will be code signed with the distribution certificate. i.e it will use distribution certificate which we used to submit app on appstore. Previously when you use "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" then you can create an ipa from development profile also. but now on it requires distribution certificate for "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment".

2) When you select "Save for Development Deployment" then you can distribute your app using development profile. it just like previously we did with "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment". i.e you can create your ipa file using development certificate also and you can distribute this ipa to your client and testers who's device id is present in your provisioning profile.

Comment: You mean that the difference between "Save for Development Deployment" and “Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.” is just the difference between distribution certificate and development certificate?And the intallation of the app is just the same?

Comment: yes...when you use distribution certificate to submit app to testflight you can upload that app to appstore. but when you use development certificate then you can not submit that app to appstore you can distribute it locally.

Comment: Both  "Save for Development Deployment" and “Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" require the device be registered under your Apple Developer account at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/  Is that correct?

Comment: If you are using "Save for Ad Hoc Development" then there is no necessary to add the device to your provisioning profile as it is signed with distribution certificate which we used to submit app on app store. Bt for "development development" you need register device.

Comment: Are you sure @Nik? Unfortunately I tested and the installation failed on not provisioned UUID...

Comment: Hi @StefanoGiacone either If you use development development or ad hoc deployment you need to have the devices registered in you provisioning profile. For more detail explanation about the use you can refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

In that they have mentioned about development deployment you can use your development certificate.

Comment: So questions: 1) Can i use testflight with `save for Development`? 2) Can i share app with diawi when `save for Development`? 3) Is it true, that in both cases i need devices to be registered in provision profiles?

Comment: 1) As per my knowledge you won't be able to use testflight with save for development as to upload app on testflight it is necessary to have "ad hoc certificate". 2) For second question, yes you can share app with diawi by using "save for development". 3) For testflight it is not necessary to have your device registered as it is signed with ad hoc certificate but for save for development you need to have your device registered.

Comment: it helps and understand well when you have different team with single developer account. so developer have don't access to distribute only development

Answer (score 6):

I think:

1.***The purpose of "Save for Development Deployment"*** is that If you don't have the distribution certificate,you can also use development certificate to distribute your app!

2.***The difference between "Save for Development Deployment" and “Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.”*** ,the difference is the type of certificate.

Answer (score 2):

With Ad Hoc Development Apple gives you an URL to send to your registered testers. With Development Deployment, your users have to install the .ipa.